# export an xls file with Bold, color, column-width etc. in angular2 code

Tags: angular, export-to-excel

I want to export a xls file from Angular2 code. I can see few options to do so. However, I want to Bold column-headers, change color of headers, adjust a column width etc. through the code.
Can anyone please advice on how to do the same with a sample example?

Comment: Does that help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333537/how-to-generate-excel-through-javascript

Comment: It seems option suggested in the link is through java-script.

Comment: Found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177183/how-to-export-json-to-csv-or-excel-angular-2/39177776