# How to export array of objects to an excel in angular4?

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects as shown below

```
    [
        {   "FirstName": "John", 
            "LastName": "Parker", 
            "Age": "23", 
            "Cat": "23g",
            "SOP": "Active"
        },
        {   "FirstName": "Rose", 
            "LastName": "Jackson", 
            "Age": "44", 
            "Cat": "44g",
            "SOP": "InActive"
        }
    ]
```

how can i export this data along with the `logo` of the company to the excel and download the same.

Any suitable plugin to write `objects data` and `logo image` to excel?

Comment: i recommand you to do this in back-end side.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this function , it works fine with me

```
//DOWNLOAD
  download(){
    var csvData = this.ConvertToCSV( this.data);
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    var blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: 'text/csv' });
    var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    var x:Date = new Date();
    var link:string ="filename_" + x.getMonth() +  "_" +  x.getDay() + '.csv';
    a.download = link.toLocaleLowerCase();
    a.click();

  }


// convert Json to CSV data in Angular2
  ConvertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    var row = "";

    for (var index in objArray[0]) {
        //Now convert each value to string and comma-separated
        row += index + ',';
    }
    row = row.slice(0, -1);
    //append Label row with line break
    str += row + '\r\n';

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','

            line += array[i][index];
        }
        str += line + '\r\n';
    }
    return str;
  }
```

Comment: This is awesome! Your "ConvertToCSV" doesn't escape already present commas though, any idea on how to cater for this?

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to do this from backend side but still, there are some packages available to do same, check it out

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-csv
- [How to Export JSON to CSV or Excel - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39177998/5043867)