# How to save json data as excel file using angular 4 and node js?

Tags: json, node.js, angular

I want to download the list of json data as excel file using node js and angular 4. How to send the response in node js and how can I download response as a excel file in angular 4?

Comment: [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44595642/5894421) may help you

Comment: thanks..it helped me to complete my work.