# Export TypeScript to Excel with style

Tags: excel, angular, typescript, npm, xlsx

I use **[xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)** to write data to xlsx file.

My code :

```
const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(myData);
const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'mySheet': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['mySheet'] };
XLSX.writeFile(workbook, 'MyData.xlsx');.
```

I want to style the cell ,how and whether it can be done?

I tried to use `s` but it did not work:

```
worksheet['B1'].s = {font: {bold : true}};
```

**EDIT**

"The docs claim that's only available in the pro version"- This comment is true, I did not notice.

So my question is different:

Is there **any other way** to export to excel file with style?

Comment: The docs claim that's only available in the pro version

Comment: @user184994. correct! I did not notice. Is there any other way to do that? I do not mind using another package.

Comment: npm install xlsx-style --save
The second answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177183/how-to-export-json-to-csv-or-excel-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

you can use exceljs package instead of xlsx in angular.