# How to implement Observable in function

Tags: javascript, angular

According to **luwojtaszek** answer in this topic:
[How to Export JSON to CSV or Excel - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177183/how-to-export-json-to-csv-or-excel-angular-2)
I implemented a pice of code:

```
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data']};
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, ExcelService.toExportFileName(excelFileName));
  }
}
```

Above code works fine and eventually generates an excel file.
Because of size of data it takes few seconds to generate a file (almost 10 MB).
I would like to show some fancy animation to notify user, that it is in progress.
The problem is I can't return an observable, or I don't know how to use it properly.

I created a service that I inject through constructor and then I subscribe to function this way:

```
this.loading = true;      
return this._excelExporterService.exportAsExcelFile(this.data,'file').subscribe(x=> {
    if(x)
    this.loading = false;
})
```

and this is how my service looks:

```
  public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
    const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data']};
    let x: boolean;
    XLSX.writeFile(workbook, ExcelExporterService.toExportFileName(excelFileName));
    return Observable.of(true);

  }
```

Comment: What about adding await for exportAsExcelFile function and return XLSX.writeFile ;;

public async exportAsExcelFile ... return XLSX.writeFile(workbook....}

this._excelExporterService.exportAsExcelFile(this.data,'file').then(d =>{ this.loading = false }).catch(e=>{})

Comment: Edited the answer to include an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In the service 
`import { of } from 'rxjsx;`
In the function:
return of(true) ;`

Answer (score 0):

[documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#writing-functions)
you can use:

```
public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return new Observable((obs)=> { 
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = {Sheets: {'data': worksheet}, SheetNames: ['data']};
        obs.next(true);
        XLSX.writeFileAsync(excelFileName, workbook, () => {
            obs.next(false);
        });
    });
}
exportAsExcelFile(json_any, 'testName').subscribe((resp:boolean)=>{
    loadind(resp);
});
```

Comment: Is seems that writeFileAsync is missing. Could you provide full example?